# My flash preloader works in IE7 to IE10 but not in IE11

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, flash, swfobject

So I made a custom preloader for a flash game of mine. Im using the swfObject library to embed the flash game.

The preloader shows up in Firefox, Chrome and IE7-10 but it doesn't show up in IE11. It shows a white screen until the game is loaded, the flash game is receiving the parameters OK and the callback function tells the flash object is created (in IE11 it is created when the white screen starts). Ive already tried to change IE11 user agent to other IEs and it didnt work.

Javascript Code: (swfObject)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var flashvars = {};
flashvars.idSessao = "<?php echo $idSessao; ?>";
flashvars.sessionPHP = "<?php echo session_id(); ?>";
flashvars.lingua = "pt";

var params = {};
params.menu = "false";
params.wmode = "transparent";
params.allowFullScreen = "true";
params.allowScriptAccess = "always";
params.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
params.pluginspage = "http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer";
params.bgcolor = "#FFFFFF";

var attributes = {};
attributes.id = "as3_js";
attributes.name = "jogo";
attributes.align = "middle";

swfobject.embedSWF('jogos/novo<?php echo $rowPresGame['GameRefID']; ?>.swf', 'flash', '900', '600', '9.0.0',  false, flashvars, params, attributes,swfCallback);


function swfCallback( event ) 
{
      console.log(event.success);
}  
</script>
```

AS3 Code

```
loadGame()

function loadGame()
{
    loadbar.visible = false;

    lang = root.loaderInfo.parameters.lingua;
    idSession = root.loaderInfo.parameters.idSessao;
    phpSession = root.loaderInfo.parameters.sessionPHP;

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,  loadGameProgress);


}

function loadGameProgress(e:Event):void
{
    var totalload = loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
    var currentload = loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;

    loadbar.scaleX = currentload/totalload
    loadbar.visible = true;

    if (loaderInfo && currentload == totalload)
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,  loadGameProgress);
        play(); 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know why it does this, but I think the recommended procedure is to have an .swf act as a preloader - a small ~50 kB file loads the bigger game. No browser can withhold the preloader from working, because it has to work to preload.

Comment: Im going to give it a try.

Comment: @Pimgd Yep, earlier it was enough to use two frames, but IE11 caches the full SWF before allowing Flash player to display it, thus eliminating preloader functionality in single-SWF applications. So now one has to build two SWFs, so that stupid IE11 will fully load the preloader before the main SWF will start loading, and your preloader will be displayed.